# Dynamically loading images in Safari on iPad 2 causes memory leak

Tags: javascript, html, ios, image, memory

I'm developing a game on HTML5 and it has a memory leak problem when running on iPad 2. In the memory trace, I see loaded images occupied almost used memory and it's never released.

So, It's reason why I want to know extractly: how does browser keep images on memory?

In my imagination, the cycle begins when HTML parser of browser reach an Image DOM element, it loads the image data from URL into memory and render it to screen.

So, when is the image data released from memory? Or how to release it manually?

Comment: Do you keep references to your image nodes alive, even after they have been removed from the document? This includes _variables_, _Object_ properties, items in _Arrays_, and includes in constructors where they were made but are no longer being used, but were not set to (e.g.) `null`.

Comment: It's not the browser. It's your code.

Comment: if you load the image directly then it's your code. if you use base64(dataurls) then it's a bug

Comment: Okay, my game works correctly on browser right now. But to run on iPad 2, i used a technology named Cocoonjs (http://www.ludei.com/tech/cocoonjs), it's a similar-browser wrapper for HTML5 game to run as native app on iOS. It kept all loaded images on memory and I think it's reason why out-of-memory occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Some code could be interesting, to see how you manage your images in your applicayion.

Anyway a good tips for memory leak problems with images on ipad 3 (not sure for the 2 but i believe yes) it's to use a simple CSS Rule like that :

```
img{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
}
```

This simple rule will enable the 3D acceleration, but use it only when you really need it.

Hope it helps a little

Comment: I think my problem is on memory allocation while your solution is for CPU consumption.